# Programatically upload a project to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto, boto3

I've been using [Boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#client). I can't find a way to automatically upload my local compressed Meteor.js project to an environment of my Elastic Beanstalk application. It's possible to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Automatically upload means what are you looking for? Can you elaborate a use case or some thing?

Comment: I got a local script using BOTO3. I need to make the script take a compressed local meteor.js project and upload it to an environment of my elastic beanstalk application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have your project zipped up, you perform the following:

1. Upload your ZIP file to an S3 bucket.
2. Create a new Elastic Beanstalk Application Version (`create-application-version`) to create a new version of your application, directing the version to use your ZIP file uploaded to S3.
3. When ready, deploy the new version to your application using `update-environment` specifying the label of your new version.